# Inheriting units in OpenMDAO

Tags: inheritance, openmdao

I have a series of components in a group where some of the components are written to be general purpose rather than specific to my application. I would like to have the inputs and outputs of these general components inherit units from the params they are connected to in their parent group. Is this possible? I am not sure it is really necessary, and everything seems to be working fine, but I keep getting the following warning:

```
Unit Conversions
GeneralComp.Output -> SpecificComp.Input : None -> kW
```

I could foresee a problem where the units passed in to the GeneralComp should be converted at some point, but are not since the units are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have a way to inherit units from src connections. Generally speaking that would be way to risky, and would likely cause [some satellite to crash into mars](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9909/30/mars.metric.02/). I like units to be explicit in this case, since not specifying them works fine (we simply take the value you give and pass it downstream).

Why not add a 'units' init arg to your components, so you can specify it at init time?

Comment: could you be more specific? Do you want the unit itself (e.g. 'm/s') or do you want a value in the units of a param?

Comment: The easiest way is to go down to the component that owns that parameter, via <problem>.root.somegroup.someothergroup.component.params['param_name']